# How to create a Task from already asynchronous code?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I have some code that's already asynchronous - just not using the Task system.  I would like to make it a lightweight Task, if possible, so that code may leverage it as a Task.

So I want to take this:

```
void BeginThing(Action callback);
```

And turn it into this pseudocode:

```
Task MyBeginThing() {
   Task retval = // what do I do here?
   BeginThing(() => retval.Done())
   return retval;
}
```

Is this possible? I don't want to use a mutex and another thread as a solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`TaskCompletionSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Task MyBeginThing() {
   var taskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
   BeginThing(() => taskSource.SetResult(null));
   return taskSource.Task;
}
```

This is also fairly common for adapting APIs that use events to signal asynchronous completion. If it is an old school Begin/End async pair (aka the Asynchronous Programming Model or APM) [`TaskFactory.FromAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync(v=vs.110).aspx) is also useful.